How does ground effect work with a banked wing?
How would an explanation of ground effect such as this one from Peter Kämpf be modified to account for a highly banked wing?
A paraglider and HP canopy pilot told me that when he banks a wing to touch a tip to the ground (as a trick) that he feels resistance and has to add control pressure to complete the maneuver. Presumably, this is due to ground effect.
I'm still wrapping my head around ground effect, and this isn't quite fitting with my mental imagery. The "cushion of air" goes away, the down wash is no longer blocked, etc....
Just a guess: maybe the ground is blocking the spanwise flow?

"I'm still wrapping my head around ground effect, and this isn't quite fitting with my mental imagery. The "cushion of air" goes away, the down wash is no longer blocked, etc....": this might help.

A short version of A.C.A.'s answer:
Peter's answer ends with "This effect disappears once the wing is far enough from the ground."  So for a bank that is steep enough and close enough to the ground, the lower wing sees more ground effect: more lift and less drag.  That's the only modification.  The lower wing sees more.
Let's apply that to your friend's observations.
"More lift" on the lower wing explains why he needs to increase (roll) control pressure, to avoid rolling out of the bank.
"Less drag" predicts that his yaw rate would reduce.  If he had a rudder (paragliders don't), he'd have to apply more of that too.  But if his "trick" is more like a pirouette than steady knife-edge flight, and his yaw control is a side effect of commanding roll, then that's yet another reason to command extra roll.

Thanks, that also helps, and maybe that's all there is to it. But consider this: at the wing tips there is spanwise flow. Wouldn't that interact differently with the ground than downwash? The pictures I've seen of tip drags have the wing almost perpendicular to the ground. E.g. https://www.fai.org/news/swoop-freestyle-international-open-saudi-arabia

A startling photo!  Such a maneuver must have a high pitch rate and other dynamic effects, which a steady-state analysis would miss.  @PeterKampf???

When an aircraft is shorter than its wingspan from the ground, the ground effect happens. Because of the ground's interference with the downwash and wingtip vortices, it increases lift and decreases the generated drag.
Relating to this concern, banking also involves causing a horizontal component of lift that enables the aircraft to change its direction by tilting the aircraft wings relative to the main part, which is the horizontal plane.
Moreover, in a situation where the plane is in a banked position, the lower wing is closer to the ground than the higher wing. At this time, the lower wing increases lift and reduces drag more than the higher wing. Following this, a rolling moment may happen. So, the aircraft might require more aileron input to keep a stable banked position due to the stronger lift on the lower wing.
Generally, pilots need to be aware of these changes, especially during low-altitude maneuvers like takeoff, landing, or low passes, since the aircraft's stability and control responses can be affected.
In conclusion, an airplane with banked wings experiences asymmetric lift and drag when it flies close to the ground because the lower wing is more affected by the ground effect than the upper wing. In order to preserve stable and organized flight, I recommend the pilots modify their control inputs due to the potential impact of this asymmetry on the rolling and turning dynamics of the aircraft.

Thank you, I learned stuff while reading this, but my question is more about how the causes (e.g. ground wash and wing tip vorteces) themselves are affected by the large bank angle.

Welcome to Aviation SE!  But please be careful that your answers really answer the question.  Don't bother to define terms (bank, ground effect) that the questioner used and already understands.
